# How to insert multiple row on php mysql but if record is empty will not saved

Tags: php, mysql

I want to save multiple insert record on database with form like table grid, but only contains value will be saved, if empty will not inserted.

My table structure is:

```
kode_barang     varchar
nama            varchar
quantity        float
satuan          float
harga           float
jumlah          float
```

Table grid to save , but only contain value will saved into database
[![table grid to save , but only contain value will saved into database][1]][1]

My HTML Code is :

```
<tr>
<td > <input type ="text" name="kode2"></td>
<td > <input type ="text" name="nama2"></td>
<td ><input type ="text" name="quantity2"> </td>
<td > <input type ="text" name="satuan2"></td>
<td > <input type ="text" name="harga2"></td>
<td > <input type ="text" name="jumlah2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td > <input type ="text" name="kode3"></td>
<td > <input type ="text" name="nama3"></td>
<td ><input type ="text" name="quantity3"> </td>
<td > <input type ="text" name="satuan3"></td>
<td > <input type ="text" name="harga3"></td>
<td > <input type ="text" name="jumlah3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td > <input type ="text" name="kode4"></td>
<td > <input type ="text" name="nama4"></td>
<td ><input type ="text" name="quantity4"> </td>
<td > <input type ="text" name="satuan4"></td>
<td > <input type ="text" name="harga4"></td>
<td > <input type ="text" name="jumlah4"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td > <input type ="text" name="kode5"></td>
<td > <input type ="text" name="nama5"></td>
<td ><input type ="text" name="quantity5"> </td>
<td > <input type ="text" name="satuan5"></td>
<td > <input type ="text" name="harga5"></td>
<td > <input type ="text" name="jumlah5"></td>
</tr>
```

description about my problem is on this link picture :

**https://kek.gg/i/BnMy7.png**

Comment: And what's the problem? You should probably not execute the `mysqli_query` call if the conditions do not apply

Comment: post your html code as well.

Comment: above i already edit my question with more detail about my code and my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try only when every data is not Empty

```
if(!empty($data)){
 insert();
}
```

this will only run when your `$data` have some value in it.

Comment: but my problem is, i make some row record about 12 row, and if i input only 2 record will be inserted

Comment: i already try to make some insert but not succefull, please help